How to force PhpStorm to always show popup code completion alongside (AI) inline completion
Is there anyway of always showing the popup code completion alongside (AI) inline completion in PhpStorm/WebStorm?
My default view looks like below, where the inline completion shows, but there's no popup code completion.

If I used the shortcut to open the code completion block, I can get both both code suggestions like I want. However, I want to have both always appear automatically. Is this possible?

